# Nested form of rails giving issue of Unpermitted parameter: :image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

I am able to submit form, but parameters of image is missing. Since, it's a nested form not able to get where I went wrong.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :identification, foreign_key: 'user_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :identification, :image
end
```

**identification.rb**

```
class Identification < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end
```

**image.rb**

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :file, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  validates_presence_of :file
end
```

**registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<h2>Sign up form</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <h3>Identification</h3>
  <div>
    <%= f.fields_for :identification do |i| %>
      <div>
        <%= i.label :full_name %> <br />
        <%= i.text_field :full_name %> <br />
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= i.fields_for :image do |image| %>
          <%= image.label :image %> <br />
          <%= image.file_field :file %> <br />
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

**Issue on log**

```
 Unpermitted parameter: :image
```

I tried to change :

```
<%= i.fields_for :image do |image| %>
```

with

```
<%= i.fields_for :image_attributes do |image| %>
```

But still getting:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :image_attributes
```

I think I need:

```
user[identification_attributes][image_attributes][file]
```

Where I went wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your permitted parameters.  See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: You need to change `i.fields_for :image do |image|` to `i.fields_for :images do |image|`

Comment: @FabianWinkler I tried that too, that doesn't work either.

Comment: Could you post the code of your controller? Or at least the lines affecting the permitted parameters? And the logs around the line `Unpermitted parameter: :image`?